# Проблема с подключением php 7.3 перестает работать phpmyadmin

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache, phpmyadmin

Имеется LAMP и с помощью sudo a2enmod и a2dismod я легко переключаюсь между версиями php 8.0, 8.1. 8.2, 8.3. Устанавливаю версию php 7.3 или 7.4 перестает работать оваливается БД, phpmyadmin не работает. В логах apache ошибка такая:

AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'static' (T_STATIC) in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php on line 272'

php7.3 и 7.4-mysql установил и включил его в конфигурации, настройка виртуального хоста тоже не принесла желаемого результата.

Мне это очень нужно сайт перенести который работатет на php 7.3, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Тебе текст ошибки перевести? Не работает твой сайт на 7.3 (если эта ошибка с него и он работает на +8,0).

Comment: сайт относительно древний, у него в растройках phpmyadmin версия php 7.3

Comment: Причём тут вообще PMA? Это лог с сайта или PMA? PMA какой версии?

Comment: phpMyAdmin Информация о версии: 5.1.1deb5ubuntu1, это лог при попытке перехода на site.ru/phpmyadmin

Comment: У PMA нет таких путей. Обратись лучше к специалисту. Ты не понимаешь ни что такое PMA ни связи/зависимости компонентов сервера. С свежая версия PMA может и не работать с мёртвой версией php.

Comment: Да не понимаю, пытаюсь разобраться)